# Calling methods which not throws exceptions in 'try' block

Tags: java, optimization, exception

I've read some Java exceptions handling best practices, but there's one moment which is not described in any literature I saw.
I've got some methods to be called only if all the "try" block was executed successfully. Is it correct to call methods, which do not throw any exceptions in "try" block just because they need to be called only if all the block was executed successfully? Or is it better to make a success flag which will be setted to false in any "catch" block and call further methods after the statement only if the flag is not false? Are there any style guides about it?

Comment: I am very confused by what you're describing. Rather than some big vague explanation of the code, show with code what you're attempting to describe instead.

Comment: It's totally fine to call methods that do not throw any exception from inside a try block.

Comment: From a Clean Code perspective this would be the most natural approach, don't use an additional flag creating mor complex code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do this. If you have something that needs to be executed only if the try block executes successfully, put it at the end of the try block. A boolean flag is unnecessary.

If you need to run code regardless of whether or not the try block executed successfully, put it in a finally block.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this method anyway - use finally block.
Also you can use any methods with any exceptions within anywhere including catch block. Just handle these exceptions too within this catch block. That's it - provide another try/catch within you catch block and do it as deep as necessary.

Comment: OP: "Is it correct to call methods, which do not throw any exceptions in **try** block "?

Answer (score 1):

**The only think that matters is readability.**

If you want to be explicitly clear that some methods need to be called only when the code in `try` block succeeded, then:

- you can used some additional logic to be explicit,
- or you can use comments to make this clear.

**In both cases it should be obvious from the code.**